# having default data as selected in select material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have some data which i am passing as props and i want it to be my default selected  value .
Here is the code for select in material ui that i am using .However the user should also have the option of selecting other courses too .
the passed props from parent is coursename which can be used as this.props.coursename

```
<form className={classes.root} autoComplete="off">
                   <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                   <InputLabel htmlFor="age-simple">Courses</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                     value={this.state.courseselected}
                     onChange={this.handleCourseChange}
                     inputProps={{
                        name: "courseselected",
                        id: "age-simple"
                    }}
                >

                 {CourseData.map(item => {
               return <MenuItem value={item._id}>{item.title}</MenuItem>;
             })}
           </Select>
         </FormControl>
       </form>
```

I am passing a props parent component and i want that course to be shown as selected by default .

Answer (score 0):

You must have initialized courseSelected in the state either in constructor or on class level

On constructor level

```
    constructor(props){
         super(props){
         this.state = {
              courseSelected: “”
         }
     }
```

Or on class level

```
    state = {
         courseSelected: “”
    }
```

So to show default value in the drop down

just change

```
   courseSelected: “”
```

To

```
   courseSelected: this.props.coursename
```